# Does pandas need to close connection?

Tags: python, pandas

When using pandas "read_sql_query", do I need to close the connection? Or should I use a "with" statement? Or can I just use the following and be good?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

sql = """
    SELECT * FROM Table_Name;
    """
engine = create_engine('blah')

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)

print df.head()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/io/sql.py), I can't find a `con.close()` method on any SQL connection object, only the `cursor` objects for the queries.

I'd close for safe-measure. Whether you do that using `with` or not is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, to me is wouldn't make sense to close the connection if it is taking the connection as an argument.

Comment: Right, because it would need to re-open for subsequent queries.

Comment: Connections should generally close when they go out of scope. That said, it's better to close connections when appropriate.

Answer (score 32):

For anyone who finds this question and wonders how to close the connection in this example, the [following method](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/7tWKFRm1xTU) worked for me: `engine.dispose()`

Comment: For good measure, here is the reference to official SQLAlchemy documentation with additional explanation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#engine-disposal